# Ошибки в старом проекте после обновления android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

После обновления версии Android Studio (или по какой-то другой причине), в ранее работающем проекте приложение перестает работать, и во всяких созданных классах, методах и полях - ошибки (Cannot resolve symbol '...') в огромном количестве...

Откуда они берутся и как это исправить?!

Comment: пробовали rebuild сделать?

Comment: Sync Project with Gradle File - clean project и rebuild

Comment: пробовал rebuilt и invalidate caches делать, ничего не изменилось